# How to Set the Default values from available values Through Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportmanager

I have an SSRS report which contains the students details, which will display all the results(passed and failed) of the students. I get the options for the parameter by selecting "Specify values" under the Parameter's "Default Values" setting. However when report gets executed I want "Passed" to be displayed as default and with dropdown to select "Failed" as an option in the report. How can I achieve it?

[reference pic of parameter's Default values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45zrn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your parameter, if you right click your parameter - >  parameter properties -> Default Value -> click "Add" button and then type ="Passed" (assuming this string is what the report is expecting)

[image]

Comment: As harry intimated, this must match the parameter **value**. So if, in your available values,  you have a label "passed" with a value of 1 and a label "failed" with a value of 0 then you would simply enter `1` in the default value

Comment: After specifying the value as mentioned by Harry and when Executing the report no results came by default whereas manually the values should be selected for results in the parameters. (Note: When I don't specify "Specify values" and execute I get the data for both pass and failed.)

Comment: Can you please show us your where statement which shows how you deal with your parameter? Also, can you confirm that the string is actually ehat the database has not not a corresponding value like Alan Schofield has mentioned above?